# fetch other tables data based on if condition on particular field in one table in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have three tables

**meeting** (id,name,weekly_plan_id,is_agent)

**weekly_plan** (id,plan)

**meeting_agent** (meeting_id,agent_id) this is mapping table

**meeting_contact** (meeting_id,contact_id) this is mapping table

now what i want? to fetch table based on if condition in **meeting** tables **is_agent** field if it is **1** then i want to fetch data from 
**meeting_agent** table else from **meeting_contact**

```
SELECT m.*,IF(m.is_agent='1',ma.agent_id, mc.contact_id) AS pid 
FROM 
    meeting m
JOIN weekly_plan wp ON wp.id=m.weekly_plan_id
JOIN meeting_agent ma ON ma.meeting_id=m.id
JOIN meeting_contact mc ON mc.meeting_id=m.id
WHERE wp.id=9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have to specify this logic over and over for each column :

```
SELECT m.*,
       IF(m.is_agent='1',ma.agent_id, mc.contact_id) AS pid,
       IF(m.is_agent='1',ma.col1, mc.col1) ,
       IF(m.is_agent='1',ma.col2, mc.col2) ,
       ..........
```

Or use `LEFT JOIN` with this condition inside the `ON` clause, and one of the tables columns will be null and the other will be filled with data.

Comment: @JunedAnsari I would recommend that you take a deep breath before you downvote people that are trying to help you. Your rep status is bouncing around and kinda obvious. Deleting comments too.